# Mavericks and Apple menu positions

Tags: itunes, osx-mavericks

Since I installed Mavericks, I had been having some issues about the position of menues in Apple applications like Finder, XCode, Safari and iTunes,

After moving the program window, their menues still appear at the previous position. Please watch this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kltifsfabybyjbb/Mavericks%20Menu.mov) to understand what I mean. It's very difficult to work in that way.

Did anybody have the same problem? Anybody knows how to solve it?